# How to mute Ambient sound coming from device while microphone calibration using AudioKit?

Tags: swift, swift4, audiokit, avkit

I am using AudioKit for microphone calibration. Mine code is as below:

```
class Manager: NSObject {

    var mic: AKMicroPhone!
    var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
    var silence: AKBooster!
    var defaultGain = 0.25
    init() {
        super.init()
        AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
        mic = AKMicrophone()

        // An instance of AKFrequencyTracker() what will track the pitch of signal
        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)

        // An instance of AKBooster() which is AudioKit version of Apple’s Mixer Node. The gain parameter is an amplification factor (Default: 1, Minimum: 0).
        silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: defaultGain)
        }

    func startCalibration() {
        AudioKit.output = silence
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

So, the `startCalibration()` is my function for starting microphone calibration to measure frequency. But while using this function there is sound coming from my mobile speakers it is similar to the input voice.